# What is the name of this green plant with thin leaves?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I've seen this in Scotland between Balmaha and Inversnaid:

[image]

A higher resolution is here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Balmaha-Inversnaid-9.jpg

What is the name of this green plant with very thin leaves?
(I guess it was most of the time about 60cm high, but I don't quite remember)

Comment: Some kind of Equisetum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisetum With this picture it is pretty hard to figure it out more detailed.

Comment: Could be too-many things. Higher resolution of whole landscape is usually NOT helpful. What  needed, is more close-up. So that it could be observed in a technical way. As well, I could not find any possible-reproductive-structure. You could go through this page [Are there any guideline about species-identification questions?](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/are-there-any-guideline-about-species-identification-questions). I think it may help where to look for before photograph it.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Thank you for the link. For future questions, I will try to follow these guidelines. However, I have no idea how reproductive structures look like for plants.

Comment: To me it looks like many other things such as 1. some tropical angiosperms like [*Alternanthera philoxeroides*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternanthera_philoxeroides) (syn. [Telanthera philoxeroides](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl/record/tro-1100575) ), amaranthaceae; [*Leucas aspera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucas_aspera),Lamiaceae;  [*Hygrophila spinosa*] syn *asteracanthus longifolia* (acanthaceae), etc. I think this is a very common growth found in broad groups from bryophyte to grasses and dicots.

Comment: Reproductive structures mean inflorescence, flowers , fruits seeds in angiosperm, cones and seeds in gymnosperms, sorus and cones in pteridophytes, capsules in bryophytes, and in case of algae they are oogonium and antheridium. Are they very difficult to recognize? flowers and fruits couldbe very tiny in shape. Btw not much discussion is possible here. You could go through plant morphology chapters in school textbooks(here these topics taught commonly class-5(10yr kids)to  8 (13yrs youths) in life science and nature studies). Though these books may contain some technical mistakes but will help

Comment: when I wrote reproductive structure 'means'; I didn't meant 'definition' (because the term 'reproductive structure' means itself). I should write 'example'. However if the language was too-technical for you, I'm sorry don't worry I think its not at all difficult to recognize a flower or inflorescence or such-sort of things emerged on the plant-body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a moss of the genus polytrichum, most likely it is [P. commune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrichum_commune) or P. formosum [image]